It seems that ”ccache“ doesn't work with CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE “emscripten.cmake”
when I was trying to add "ccache" to my cmake program, no new files were added to my ccache directory.
cmake -B build_wasm -S . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache 
I use this way to apply ccache to my cmake file.
I tried test "ccache em++/emcc" in a small project, it does work.

I tried several ways to fix my problem and found that using an absolute path rather than a relative path to set the "CCACHE_DIR" can work out.
